# Grails application from Hibernate-annotated Java POJOs

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm still new to Grails and have the following question to ask.

I'd like to develop a grails application starting with Hibernate-annotated POJOs.
Can define our entities in Hibernate-annotated POJOs and then use them in the Grails framework?

Possibly using a ready-made tool which converts from Hibernate POJOs to Grails entity definitions, if Grails cannot use Hibernate-annotated Java POJOs directly.

Comment: Yes, as I can see in docs, it's possible. Have a [look](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.17/guide/hibernate.html).

Comment: @yariash I would add that as an answer, but point out "what" is possible (using Hibernate annotated POJOs) if you do.

Comment: Start with pojos then a tool to convert to pogo. Sensibly I would start with pogo considering you later want them converted

Comment: @yariash thanks for the answer, as Joshua says, good to convert your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Yaraish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1303324/yariash) pointed out, Grails can work directly with Hibernate-annotated Java classes.

Furthermore these can be enhanced by a separate validation spec groovy file placed in the same package as the Java Class, and following Grails' naming pattern to automatically associate that spec with the Java class.

From the Grails page quoted by [@yaraish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1303324/yariash): 
(using Hibernate-native mapping ...)  "You will be able to map Grails domain classes onto a wider range of legacy systems and have more flexibility in the creation of your database schema.  Best of all, you will still be able to call all of the dynamic persistent and query methods provided by GORM!"